# NDSolve complains about DAE being structurally singular

Tags: differential-equations

So I am trying to solve a simple system as defined bellow, but NDSolve keeps complaining.

$(f'(t))^2 + (g'(t))^2 = 1$

$(\pi/2 - t)^2 = (\cos(2t) - f(t))^2 + (g(t) + \sin(2t))^2$

where $t\in[0,\pi/2]$

With the following initial conditions:
$f[0] = 1 - \pi/2,\; g[0] = 0,\; f'[0] = 1,\; g'[0] = 0$

Bellow you can see the respective Mathematica code that I am using.

```
NDSolve[ { 
  (f'[t])^2 + (g'[t])^2 == 1,
   (Pi/2 - t)^2 == (Cos[2*t] - f[t])^2 + (g[t] + Sin[2*t])^2,
  f[0] == 1 - Pi/2,
  g[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, g'[0] == 0}, {f, g}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

The error `NDSolve` gives is the following,
[image: NDSolve error]

Firstly, I do not understand fully the error. What does it mean for a DAE to be structurally singular?

Secondly, I have tried many different staff. For example, at first I did not use the initial conditions for the derivatives but an error of NDSolve indicated that I should try and provide these initial conditions, and I have tried various options of NDSolve without success. Lastly, I have tried solving the algebraic equation for $g(t)$ and substituting that into the system making it one simple differential equation, but then there are problems with division by 0 and some partial solutions that I extracted had an imaginary part which I do not want.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html

Comment: This can't be good: `Flatten@{
    NestList[D[#, t] &, (f'[t])^2 + (g'[t])^2 == 1, 1],
    NestList[D[#, t] &, (Pi/2 - t)^2 == (Cos[2*t] - f[t])^2 + (g[t] + Sin[2*t])^2, 2],
    f[0] == 1 - Pi/2, g[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, g'[0] == 0} /. t -> 0 // Reduce` returns `False`.

Comment: @Alrubaie Thank you for the reference, I have studied the documentation with no success.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am not sure I understand what that code does, could you elaborate please? Thank you.

Comment: It takes derivatives of the equations until we have a 2nd-order system. Then it substitutes the initial values and contradictory equations result.  Get rid of the `// Reduce` and you'll see the resulting system at `t == 0`. You can derive the contradiction by hand, if you wish. You'll get two different values for `f''[0]`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2, I should check the system again.